# Application of CLT to random walks

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, random-walk, stopping-times

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be an iid sequence such that $P\{X_1 = 1\} = p$, $P\{X_1 = -1\} =p$ and $P\{X_1 = 0\} = 1-2p$. We have that $E[X_1] = 0$ and $E[X_1^2] = 2p$.

Define $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ and $S_0 = 0$ and consider the natural filtration. Define the stopping time $\tau = \inf\{n\geq 0: S_n = a \text{ or } S_n = b\}$ where $a < 0 < b$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. I need to show that $\tau$ is almost surely finite. For this I am expected to use the central limit theorem.

To make life simpler, I define $\sigma = \inf\{n\geq 0: S_n = -c \text{ or } S_n = c\}$ where $c = -a \vee b$. $\tau \leq \sigma$ clearly. So I will show $\sigma$ is a.s. finite.

From the CLT, I have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left\{S_n \leq c\sqrt{2pn}\,\right\} = \Phi(c)$$
where $z\mapsto \Phi(z)$ is the distribution function of a standard normal r.v. I also have that

$$\{\sigma < \infty\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{S_n = c\text{ or } S_n = -c \}$$

I am guessing I need to use the estimates coming from the CLT but there is a $\sqrt{n}$ in there, which confuses me. Can someone give a hint on how I should continue?

Comment: How is the event $\{S_n \leq c\sqrt{2pn}\}$ related to $\sigma$?

Comment: @Did One relation that I see is $\{S_n > c\sqrt{2pn}\} \subset \{\sigma \leq n\}$ for large $n$.

Comment: Sure, for $n\geqslant1/(2p)$, this relation happens to hold, but you should be using $\{S_n>x\sqrt{2pn}\}$ for tons of other values of $x$...

Comment: @Did I am not sure of this but it is tempting to think $\cup_{x=1}^{\infty} \{S_n > x\sqrt{2pn}\} = \{\sigma \leq n\}$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\{\tau<\infty\}=\bigcup_{n}\{\tau\le n\} \text{ and } \{\tau\le n\}\subseteq\{\tau\le n+1\};
$$

$$
\therefore P\{\tau<\infty\}=\lim_{n\to\infty}P\{\tau\le n\}\ge \lim_{n\to\infty}P\{S_n\notin (a,b)\}=1.
$$

---

To see that the last limit is indeed $1$ use the CLT. Let $c_{n,1}=(a+1)/\sqrt{2pn}, c_{n,2}=(b-1)/\sqrt{2pn}$ and note that 
$$
P\{S_n\notin (a,b)\}=1-P\{c_{n,1}\le S_n/\sqrt{2pn}\le c_{n,2}\}.
$$

For any $\epsilon>0$, $\exists n_0$ s.t. $\epsilon\ge(-c_{n,1}\vee c_{n,2})$ for all $n\ge n_0$. Thus,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}P\{c_{n,1}\le S_n/\sqrt{2pn}\le c_{n,2}\}\le \Phi(\epsilon)-\Phi(-\epsilon).
$$
Now send $\epsilon\downarrow 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't understand the very last equality.

Comment: $\Phi(0) = 1/2$. So this only gives $\tau < \infty$ with probability at least one half. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Calculon Oh. That's right. I meant

$$P\{S_n\notin (a,b)\}=1-P\{(a+1)/\sqrt{2pn}\le S_n/\sqrt{2pn}\le (b-1)/\sqrt{2pn}\}\to 1$$

Comment: Now I think I understand your answer but I am not entirely sure whether it is correct. It is not obvious to me how you can allow the bounds inside the probability expression depend on $n$ in the CLT.

Comment: @Calculon Good point--but one can easily adapt the idea.

Comment: @Did I thought about writing $P\{(a+1)/\sqrt{2pm}\leq S_n/\sqrt{2pn}\ldots\}$ and letting $m$ and $n$ tend to infinity separately (the former by the MCT, the latter by the CLT). But that is not exactly the probability I want to calculate.

Comment: @Calculon For any $\epsilon>0$, $\epsilon\ge (-c_1\vee c_2)/\sqrt{2pn}$ for all $n$ large enough. Thus,

$$
1-P\{c_1/\sqrt{2pn}\le S_n/\sqrt{2pn}\le c_2/\sqrt{2pn}\}\ge 1-P\{-\epsilon\le S_n/\sqrt{2pn}\le \epsilon\}\to 1-(\Phi(\epsilon)-\Phi(-\epsilon)) \text{ as } n\to\infty.
$$

Now, take $\epsilon\downarrow 0$.